# JSlider in an MP3 player application

Tags: java

I have designed an MP3 player in java using Java layer (jl) library from javazoom. The application is functional but when i try to use a JSlider or a JProgressBar to show the progress of the playing song it doesn't work. When i use the slider in its own thread it work fine with the length of the song but it makes the sound crash and the song breaks up many times while it's playing.

Would anyone please help me fix this problem. Here is the code that i am using for the slider:

```
public void setSliderValue(int maxValue, int minValue){

    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                songSlider.setMaximum(maxValue);
                songSlider.setMinimum(minValue);
                while(songIsPlaying()){
                    songSlider.setValue((int)(maxValue - input.available()));
                    songSlider.repaint();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) { }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

SongIsPlaying() is a method I'm using to check to check if there is a song currently playing and input is the object of the FileInputStream. 
Your help would be much appreciated. 
Thank you

Harold

Comment: You should improve your question and post a valid [mcve], but one thing I can say is that your threading is all wrong, including making key Swing calls off of the EDT. Google "concurrency in Swing" for more

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the comment. I will google it and if i still struggle to solve the problem then i will come back and improve my question. Thanks again

Comment: Also this sort of code: `catch (IOException ex) { }` should never be seen. Why are you completely ignoring exceptions??

Comment: You're also using a very tight loop there, one that will hog the cpu unnecessarily. You're not needing to time things to the microsecond.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks for that too

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you so much.. the loop was very tight and by making it sleep for a second i have got it to work without any problem.. thank you very much and I'll still consider your first suggestions too .